# How to use UITapGestureRecognizer on static UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, iboutlet

How can I use `UITapGestureRecognizer` on static `UITableViewCell`? So far I just created an `IBOutlet` for a static `UITableViewCell`.

```
@IBOutlet weak var settingCell: UITableViewCell!
```

What I want is for this `IBOutlet` to trigger when the user taps this `UITableViewCell`.

```
@IBAction func share(sender: AnyObject) {
    let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [NSURL(string:"https://www.apple.com/my/itunes/")!], applicationActivities: nil)
    /* If you want to exclude certain types from sharing
    options you could add them to the excludedActivityTypes */
    vc.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypePostToTwitter]
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want, you don't need to use a UITapGestureRecognizer, you can simply set the tableView with its protocols (that you probably already made), and use this function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
     //your action comes in here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need tripleTap/doubleTap. you should add the gesture recognizer in the customTVC file.

you may want to pass a completionHandler from your tableViewController or handle it at customTVC level.

note that you'd might need to disable table view row selection

Adding gesture recognizer to TVC is similiar to adding it to any uiview. but note that awakeFromNib is not always called